# Installing Ubuntu (graphic errors)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu. I first downloaded the Ubuntu ISO file and put it in Rufus. Then booted from it in BIOS (MSI Gaming 970) and everything was fine. I've downloaded Ubuntu before, and this time it looked different. there was no Ubuntu logo nor a maroon colored background. I hit "Install Ubuntu" anyways, and came across this:

[image]

I let it sit there while I went to school, and came back and it was still there. I realized I should have installed the Nvidia Linux drivers. And so I downloaded them, and don't know actually how to run it (it's a `.run` file on Windows)

So how am I supposed to install Nvidia graphic drivers for Ubuntu when Ubuntu won't even install?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a conundrum, doesn't it? But there's a way out: **Booting with `nomodeset`**.

First assure you're booting in [UEFI mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

[image: GRUB]

Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the **Try Ubuntu...** entry and type `nomodeset` after or instead of `quiet splash`. Obs.: The **MSI Gaming 970** motherboard, depending on the revision, may need an additional parameter: `iommu=soft`.

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the live session. `nomodeset` will force a compatible low graphics (low resolution) mode.

Install Ubuntu: [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

In the first boot you'll need to repeat the process and add `nomodeset` or both. Then open dash and search for **Additional Drivers**. Select and apply the recommended Nvidia drivers version. Reboot.

The `nomodeset` parameter in no longer needed. The other parameter, `iommu=soft`, if required, will need to be made permanent. In terminal:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line starting with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"`

Save, exit, reboot. Enjoy Ubuntu!

Comment: Thank you, I now have Ubuntu running, but can't find the 200gb partition I earlier made on Windows. It only shows a 1MB of free space. I'm puzzled

Comment: @InfiniteFluff That's another question. First of all, creating partitions for Linux from Windows can't be done. Unallocated space is what the installer needs. Those instructions are included in the link above. If this answer was helpful consider accepting it.