# Devices not working with rear USB ports

Tags: 16.04, usb, keyboard, mouse

I recently installed Ubuntu on my computer on a separate (internal) hard drive from Windows, and everything works fine except it will not recognize devices plugged into the rear USB ports on my computer. Only the front ones work. I tried looking into power control, and I disabled auto-suspend for all of the USB ports, but it still does not work. When I run

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control
```

it returns everything as "on." I then tried un-plugging my devices, running

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

and plugging them back in to see what the error is, and I saw the following errors for each device:

```
device not accepting address x, error -32
unable to enumerate USB device on port x
```

When I boot into Windows, I do not have any of these problems, and the keyboard and mouse I have plugged into the rear ports work in the BIOS and on the purple Ubuntu screen that asks which OS to boot. They only stop working once the login screen appears. Please help! Thank you

*Edit* here are my hardware specifications:

- Mouse and keyboard that are not working are stock Dell devices.
- Ubuntu is running on a 120GB SSD, and Windows is on a 256 GB SSD.
- CPU is an AMD FX-6300
- Motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-970A-DS3P

Comment: Thank you. As expected, a motherboard with a "broken IOMMU". Either follow the additional instructions  posted here http://askubuntu.com/a/884608/589808 (the `iommu=soft` part, of course, not the `nomodeset`) or simply install 16.10 instead (the 4.8 kernel includes a workaround for your hardware).

Comment: I updated to 16.10 and now my devices do not work with the front ports either. I have no way to interact with my computer on Ubuntu anymore.

Comment: Have you tried the Grub parameter?

Comment: I cannot use Ubuntu at all anymore since none of the ports work.

Comment: You CAN always use them in Grub menu (unless you somehow disabled something at UEFI) because the issue occurs only after loading the graphical desktop. Please don't come here again just to say "it doesn't work" because I've installed Ubuntu in *dozens* of similar motherboards so, unlike you, I know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer was go go into terminal and type

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then in the file I added `iommu=soft` between the `""` in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` line and restarted my computer.

Comment: Yes, **exactly** like the answer I posted in comments http://askubuntu.com/a/884608/589808 ...